# How to load DAE file Arkit flutter

Tags: flutter, 3d, arkit

I tried to load dae file but It didn't show anything

If I add dae file to IOS -> Runner, it will show dae file (only IOS)

I'm using package arkit_plugin

Please help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

[image that make folder model.scnassets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mcv.png)

1. make folder "models.scnassets" on ios folder of your flutter project
2. move .dae files to "models.scnassets"

[image that open Runner.xcworkspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD88A.png)

3. open "{your flutter project folder}/ios/Runner.xcworkspace"
4. add models.scnassets folder to "Runner/Runner" of Runner.xcworkspace

```dart
void onARKitViewCreated(ARKitController controller) {

    final modelNode = ARKitReferenceNode(
        url: 'models.scnassets/dash.dae',
        position: vector.Vector3(0, 0, -1.0),
        scale: vector.Vector3.all(0.3));

    controller.add(modelNode);
  }
```

5. load .dea file on your flutter code

[Result AR on real iPhone device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVg9x.jpg)

6. done!

I hope this answer is helped you. :)

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for! Do you know if it works this way with the android aswell? If not, can you recomand a flutter plugin which works with android aswell?